# I Need details about virtual products(examples) in magento2 and how to user(customer) use that product after purchase?

Tags: magento2

I learned and understand about the simple,configurable,grouped,bundle and downloadable products but the I need some clarification about the virtual product in magento2.
I understand the downloadable product that is selling a link(E-book,song,video...etc) after purchase customer link to download the product.
But I don't know about Virtual-Products?
I Need to know---customer After purchase any Virtual-products How to use that product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to user guide:

> Virtual products — or digital goods — represent non-tangible items
>   such as memberships, services, warranties, or subscriptions and
>   digital downloads of books, music, videos, or other products. Virtual
>   products can be sold individually, or included as part of the
>   following product types:
>   1. Grouped Product
>   2. Bundle Product

[More details](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-virtual.html)

Comment: Thanks for the give the details and examples.

Comment: I Need some details---customer After purchase any Virtual-products(like any memberships or Ticket) How to use that virtual-product(through customer side)?
----

For example:
if customer buy any downloadable product- then after purchase user get the link so that use to user make download.
But
if customer buy a virtual product(like any membership or ticket) then after purchase how to get the benifts --->please give any example of process...